# Does a page have to be called to start a $_SESSION variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to separate the code that makes a call to the database (data file) from the page the user sees (view file).  So, when I create an array (my_array) on the 'data file' how do I send `my_array` to the 'view file' without the user first viewing the 'data file'?

I'm trying to use the `$_SESSIONS` variable, but if I don't go to the 'data file' first, the 'view file' does not show the relevant data.

Code on 'data page':

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $my_array=array('user 1', 'user 2', 'user 3');
    $_SESSION['users'] = $my_array;
    ?>
```

Code on 'view page':

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['users'][1];
    ?>
```

So, just to be clear, I want to see 'user 2' on the 'view page' without forcing the user to first call the 'data page'.

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: at the risk of sounding very stupid, what do you mean?

Comment: What does the user see? Where is that code?

Comment: Are you trying to say: you want to call a database without executing the file??

Comment: Am I the only one confused?

Comment: @cipher: That can't be right. OP specifically mentioned "view file"

Comment: @aguyfromhere : I don't specifically know the internals about php design patterns/architectures, but, how can you fetch a var from a session without assigning something to it. As the OP says:  `but if I don't go to the 'data file' first, the 'view file' does not show the relevant data.'`

Comment: sorry this isn't clear.  i'm trying to pass data from one file to another using php.   What's the best way?

Comment: @dwstein: there are many ways.. can use a `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`, hidden inputs or a `$_SESSION`. Could also use an `include`, `require`, or `AJAX`. There is so much code missing, mainly the HTML , that I don't know how to begin to help you.

Comment: @cipher: Normally in PHP development you have a `handler` part and an `activator` part.  This user utterly failed to explain even the basics of this problem and didn't even understand what HTML was?

Comment: Agree with you, @aguyfromhere  !

Comment: include worked beautifully, per the answer below.  Sorry for any confusion.  BTW, I know what HTML is, I just didn't think it was relevant to my question, however poorly communicated.

Comment: @dwstein: I guess so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sessions is a wrong way for sure.
Sessions have to be used to store data between user's requests.
While you have yo get your data and show it within one request for sure.

So, just [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) your 'view file' into 'data file'.

Answer (score -1):

Make user open up your 'data file'.

Do not output any html but use the `$_SESSION` var as you used.

Redirect to your  view file from data file using

```
header("location:yourviewfilepath");
```

OR,

You may point the user to your view file, use a AJAX requests to your data file, `json_encode` your `array` in the data file, `json_decode` in your view file (via Javascript), and display what you wanted to display!

There are many ways you can do *one* thing.